# C3P0 Statement.close deadlock

Tags: jdbc, deadlock, c3p0

Google returns lots of people with deadlock issues in C3P0, but none of the solutions appear to apply (most people suggest setting `maxStatements = 0` and `maxStatementsPerConnection = 0`, both of which we have).

---

I am using a `ComboPooledDataSource` from C3P0, initialised as;

```
cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":5432/" + database);
cpds.setUser(user);
cpds.setPassword(pass);
```

My `query` function looks like;

```
public static List<Map<String, Object>> query(String q) {
    Connection c = null;
    Statement s = null;
    ResultSet r = null;
    try {
        c = cpds.getConnection();
        s = c.createStatement();
        s.executeQuery(q);
        r = s.getResultSet();
        /* parse result set into results List<Map> */
        return results;
    }
    catch(Exception e) { MyUtils.logException(e); }
    finally {
        closeQuietly(r);
        closeQuietly(s);
        closeQuietly(c);
    }
    return null;
}
```

No queries are returning, despite the `query()` method reaching the `return results;` line. The issue is that the `finally` block is hanging. I have determined that the `closeQuietly(s);` is the line that is hanging indefinitely.

The `closeQuietly()` method in question is as you would expect;

```
public static void closeQuietly(Statement s) {
    try { if(s != null) s.close(); }
    catch(Exception e) { MyUtils.logException(e); }
}
```

Why would this method hang on `s.close()`? I guess it is something to do with the way I am using C3P0.

---

My complete C3P0 configuration (almost entirely defaults) can be viewed here -> http://pastebin.com/K8XDdiBg

---

`MyUtils.logException();` looks something like;

```
public static void logException(Exception e) {
    StackTraceElement ste[] = e.getStackTrace();
    String message = " !ERROR!: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < ste.length; i++) {
        if(ste[i].getClassName().contains("packagename")) {
            message += String.format("%s at %s:%d", e.toString(), ste[i].getFileName(), ste[i].getLineNumber());
            break;
        }
    }
    System.err.println(message);
}
```

---

Everything runs smoothly if I remove the `closeQuietly(s);` line. Both closing the `ResultSet` and `Connection` object work without problem - apart from Connection starvation of course.

Comment: probably the first thing to do is to dump JVM threads or use jstack to see exactly where your application is hanging. just for completeness... how is MyUtils.logException(...) defined? if you comment out the closeQuietly() calls [all three, which makes a Connection leak, or just the ResultSet and Statement versions, which i bad hygiene but c3p0 will clean up after you], do things work (until pool exhaustion)?

Comment: @SteveWaldman answer edited to reflect a few more bits of info. I have truncated the `logException()` as it iterates up the stack trace a little and was a little complex. It works fine anyway, and is used all over the place.

Comment: please do try to get a snapshot of your JVM Threads to see where your application is actually hung (eg via jstack -l).

Comment: (by the way, this issue is entirely different from the c3p0-detected "APPARENT DEADLOCK"s that, prior to the c3p0-0.9.2, sometimes necessitated turning off Statement caching. This is a freeze in your, client thread; c3p0 detects APPARENT DEADLOCKs within its own Thread pool.)

Comment: @SteveWaldman understood, I will be able to have a look at the threads and get back to you on Monday, thanks for the feedback :)